# What would a forward slash mean in a href attribute?

Tags: html

in other words, what would this do? How does it actually work

```
<li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
```

Comment: It leads to the `/` (in case if `<base>` was not specified) page of the currently opened host.

Comment: Root directory of the host - `index.html`

Comment: So it will always link to index.html or index.php? Is there any documentation for this? In the meantime thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers to the base URL of the webpage.

So if your URL is `https://example.com`, `href="/"` leads you to that.

Comment: Thank you, totally makes sense